# How do I access another table's data using a predicate?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a iPad app (XCode4.6, iOS 6.2, ARC and Storyboards).  I have a CoreData store which looks like this:

[image]

I need to access both tables given the key from the AppointmentsInfo table.  Core Data doesn't use joins, so I'm thinking something like this:

```
"aApptKey = %@ and CLientInfo.ClientKey = %@"
```

What does the working predicate look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aApptKey == %@ && client.aClientKey == %@", obj1, obj2];
```

Comment: This is what I constructed, based on your answer:  
    NSPredicate *predicate =  ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"aApptKey == %@ AND ClientInfo.aClientKey == %@",             apptSelected.aApptKey, apptSelected.aApptKey]);  
  
This is the error I'm getting:  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath ClientInfo.aClientKey not found in entity <NSSQLEntity AppointmentInfo id=1>'

                                
    AppointmentInfo *foundAppt = [AppointmentInfo MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];

Comment: The predicate you constructed does not match @Scott's suggestion.

Comment: What is different besides && and AND?  There is NO _client_.. it's _ClientInfo_

Comment: @spokane-dude: `client` is the name of your relationship. ClientInfo is the name of your entity, but that's not used when constructing predicates.

Comment: I just saw that! :D  It's been a long day... let me check the keys out... as I indicated, they are identical; for some reason it's not finding the data... hmmmmm

Comment: Figured it out... thanks guys... I really appreciate your time and help.  SD